# Multiple views call and template inclusion

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'd like to create a form to insert in multiple pages. In the example below I created a template "form.html" and tried to input in "index.html". I already have a view for index (simplified in this example). Thus, I don't know how to call myform view to include the form in index.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^form$', 'myform'),
)

# views.py
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def myform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['name'] = form.cleaned_data['name']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/form')
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})

# form.html
<form action="/form/ok" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

# index.html
....
{% include "form.html" %}
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expansion of @rockingskier's answer. I changed `myform` view to return the variable `form` and called it in the `index` view.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
)

# views.py
def myform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['name'] = form.cleaned_data['name']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/ok')
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return form

def index(request):
    args['form'] = myform
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 3):

`{% include %}`ing is a way including additional html in your template.  It does not route the user through various different `views`

In your code the user will come into `index` and be given `index.html`.  `index.html` will then `{% include %}` the contents of `form.html` inside itself but have nothing to do with the `myform` view.  Within `form.html` the template will expect a variable called `form`.  `form` has not been set in this context as it is not created in `index` and thus no form contents will get rendered. (The  tags will be as they are not dependant on the `form` variable).

All variables should be set within the `view` you are using.  As such you need to create a form object and pass it all within `index`.  At that point `form.html` within `index.html` will receive the `form` variable it is expecting.

If you decide that in `index` you do not wish to call your form `form` (say you have multiple forms so want more helpful names).  Then you can `{% including "form.html" with form=form_variable_from_index %}`.  This will essentially rename the form variable but only within that `{% include %}'d file.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#include

```
# views.py
def index(request):

    # Need to create the form here
    form = MyForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form.html', args)

def myform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['name'] = form.cleaned_data['name']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/form')
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form.html', args)
```

Views know about the one template they reference.  Templates have no idea about views, just the context/variables you hand them.